# MySQL query takes 2 minutes

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a problem.
I am running a MySQL PhpMyAdmin server and I have 3 tables:

- CandlestickData
- CandlestickDataHist1
- CandlestickDataHist2

Then I created a few with the following source query:

```
SELECT
    a.*
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        *,
        'CandlestickData' AS SOURCE
    FROM
        CandlestickData
    UNION
SELECT
    *,
    'CandlestickDataHist1' AS SOURCE
FROM
    CandlestickDataHist1
UNION
SELECT
    *,
    'CandlestickDataHist2' AS SOURCE
FROM
    CandlestickDataHist2
) AS a
ORDER BY
    a.MainKey
DESC
```

This gives me a view with 1.7 million records. When I do the following simple query on the view:

```
SELECT * FROM my_created_view;
```

It takes arround 2 minutes to execute the query. Is there a way to make it faster?

Comment: What will the client do with millions of rows?  Usually, you want to do more processing inside SQL, then return a civilized number of rows to the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can speed it up a bit using `UNION ALL` rather than `UNION`:

```
SELECT cd.*
FROM ((SELECT cd.*, 'CandlestickData' AS SOURCE
       FROM CandlestickData cd
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT cd.*, 'CandlestickDataHist1' AS SOURCE
       FROM CandlestickDataHist1 cd
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT cd.*, 'CandlestickDataHist2' AS SOURCE
       FROM CandlestickDataHist2 cd
      )
     ) cd
ORDER BY cd.MainKey DESC;
```

This will still require sorting all the data.  However, it will remove the overhead for removing duplicates.  I might venture that it would be about 50% faster.

If you really want to speed the query, you need to store all the data in a single table.  Then you can create an index for the `order by` key.

Comment: So this is the fastest it can go for that many records?

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk . . . Because of the `ORDER BY` I think this may be the best you can do.

Comment: yes, you really have removed the ability to use an index for sorting by keeping what is the same structure of data in multiple tables instead of all together in one

Comment: But then I reached the max amount of records in my table. I think I have 9.5 million records then. I don't know which error I got, but splitting the data between tables was the solution. My table has 60 columns btw!

Comment: Really depends on what you trying to do with it.
Also consider a few things:

Depending on your client (such as SSMS) you may have render issues which is also a bottleneck.
What are you trying to do with that data?
Simply selecting all data of that size with no restrictions isn't a normal use case (outside of pipe to processing app/ data warehouse) and after filtering you may have better times (especially so if the filter relies on an index)
Is all of that data going to somewhere remote? - Latency happens.
60 columns is FAT for a table and databases perform better with skinnier tables.

Comment: I have a Java program on the same server which needs to calculate indicators such as EMA, RSI, etc. over all the candlesticks. Indeed I don't need to use `SELECT *`, but the query itself isn't faster with specifying just 3 columns. Do you have any further tips :) ?

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk - Limit??  The Limit is something like 64TB.  That's probably hundreds of billions of rows, not a mere 9.5 million.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so we can further diagnose this bogus limit.